# Using SizeF for user control dimensions

Tags: c#

As the tittle says I am looking for a way to use SizeF instead of normal Size for setting and getting Control dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls are using integer values internally and the size and locations cannot be set to float numbers.

`SizeF` has a `ToSize` method

```
Size size = sizeF.ToSize();
```

Or

```
myControl.Size = sizeF.ToSize();
```

Comment: That will just convert floats to integers, right? Do you know of any other way to draw a Control at a precise location on form?

Comment: In WinForms the highest possible precision is pixel precision. However, in the Paint event you can apply anti aliasing and other effects when drawing that simulate a sub-pixel precision. Why do you need a higher precision for controls?

Answer (score 1):

Controls are backed by the Windows API, which use integer based (pixel) sizing.  As such, `SizeF` would not be appropriate or have any effect.  You could always use a `SizeF`, then map to a `Size` when you set the values.

Note that, in WPF, all of the location and size types now use double precision, and do allow adjustments smaller than per pixel, since they're being rendered using DirectX instead of as windows handles.